# Predicting Composition of Chemical Compounds

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, clustering, predictive-modeling, word-embeddings

I have a dataset which has names of compounds and their compositions. Like below

Sulphuric Acid=>[H,S,O] (Hydrogen, sulphur, oxygen)
Oxalic Acid=>[H,C,O]
Sodium Oxalate=>[Na,C,O]
Potassium Sulphate=>[K,S,O]
...

Now I would need to train a model which can tell me Sodium Sulphate as [Na,S,O]. Note that sodium sulphate represents something not in training dataset.
I have tried searching for possible ideas but nothing came up. Then I thought it could be hierarchical clustering like

```
 Sodium-Oxalate
    |    |
Oxalate  Sodium
|  |      |
C  O      Na
```

But then in hierarchical clustering the base/leafs are different. But here they are shared. Its like a graph. So What machine learning algorithm can help? Any other clustering? NLP/word clustering (if yes How)?

Another approach I could think of is like `Word2Vec` where I generate embeddings for each word (C,H,Sodium), all will have embeddings. And based on what is closer to the word I am asking I will give output. But this needs huge amount of data. I only have around 1k common compounds. And the approach won't generalize to any problem like this with less data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a one-hot encoding of the elements in your training set (H, C, I etc.) and the same for the chemical descriptors ('acid', 'oxalic' etc.). Then try feeding the data to a simple feed-forward neural network, mapping the one-hot encodings of the descriptors as your `x_train` and `x_val` to the chemical elements, which are your `y_train` and `y_val`.

For the encodings, take a look at the [Scikit learn encoders.](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html)

I think such a simple approach may work, as the chemical names are logically named, so any experienced chemist knows exactly which elements to expect in a compound, given its name. Your problem doesn't require further information in the predictions, e.g. the actual chemical makeup, like $CH_3CH_2OH$ (ethanol).

Regarding a small amount of data: look into something like K-fold cross validation. Using this, you select some portion of the data to be your validation data, and train the model. You then repeat this process, selection a different portion of the data. This will help make the most of a limited dataset, although it may introduce overfitting because your model will eventually have seen all the data!

Here is a schematic of this method:

[image: k-fold cross validation]

[Scikit Learn has a class](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html) that implements it for you.

Comment: Sorry If I have not been clear, I have to predict Elements given a compound name, so are you suggesting this as a multi-class classification where my output will have Elements probabilities and Input will have compound name? Also a concern is that I have only 1k entries so any Deep Learning Solution is inherently at a disadvantage since they need huge data.

Comment: @faizan - Using a few feed forward layers isn't going to require large amount of data, as you may only have a few hundred parameters. See my edits above for more information :-)